# Update body through default template class

Tags: dart, flutter

Anyone here know Flutter/Dart

i have a defaultLayout which looks a little bit like this

```
final title = Data.appTitle;
var pages = [HomeScreen(), SearchPage(), LivePage(), AccountPage()];
String _currentRoute;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text(title),
        ),
        body: childViewBody(),  //each class that extends Default() can modify this method to change body
        //...Other Layout. BotAppBar is a custom widget
        bottomNavigationBar: BotAppBar(
            onTap: (index) {
                setState(() {
                //HERE... How can I make that whenever the BotAppBarItems are selected,.. the body is updated 
                });
            },
        items: [
            BotAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.home, tooltip: Data.homeTitle),
            BotAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.search, tooltip: Data.searchTitle),
            BotAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.near_me, tooltip: Data.liveTitle),
            BotAppBarItem(iconData: Icons.account_circle, tooltip: Data.accountTitle),
        ],
    ),
);
}

//Child class will modify this area to update screen.
childViewBody() {
    return Column(
        children: <Widget>[
            Text('Placeholder')
        ],
    );
}
```

... And this should update for any class that's extended it

for example

```
class HomePage extends Default {//...super}
class HomePageState extends DefaultState {
@override
String get title => Data.homeTitle; //updates title in parent class

childViewBody() {
    return Column{
        //Build HomeScreen Body here
    }
}
}
```

[Diagram.png](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1H1WXiXuIuEpf_AnV0Vy8nAycroUE-vjp/view?usp=drivesdk)

so how would i modify Default class that whenever the BotAppBar is selected, the body is updated... even if the current class loaded is a child class

Answer (score 0):

> You can use [HeroAnimations](https://flutter.io/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations)

to open a new window over your previous window as this is how SearchWindows should be displayed to the user.

Here's a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DExeje5_vfw) to implement it.

If `HeroAnimations` **sounds bit too much**,

> use  [Navigation](https://flutter.io/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)

Directions:

1. Create two screens
2. Navigate to the second screen using `Navigator.push`
3. Return to the first screen using `Navigator.pop`

Example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    title: 'Navigation Basics',
    home: FirstScreen(),
  ));
}

class FirstScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('First Screen'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          child: Text('Launch screen'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.push(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SecondScreen()),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Second Screen"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
          child: Text('Go back!'),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Here you go]

Comment: But it's not in need of navigator... It moves from page to page see link below. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GS2OXz9tCt-__2CR9JYD8hMx3gQISSEC/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: Yeah, so use HeroAnimations

Comment: Your method is using Navigator.push(). It puts it on top of the original... I need the template to change the body to the subclasses

Comment: Bro, use HeroAnimations, I added the link to the tutorial

Comment: Ok... I'll try implementing a body with Hero